# Zend 1.12 Pruebas Unitarias

Tags: phpunit, zend

Hola estoy tratando de configurar pruebas unitarias en Zend 1.12 pero me genera el siguiente error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Zend_Test_PHPUnit_ControllerTestCase' not found in /Users/myUser/Documents/projects/zf/tests/application/controllers/MsiControllerTest.php:7
```

phpunit.xml

```
<phpunit bootstrap="./application/bootstrap.php" colors="true">
<testsuite name="Precision Tests">
    <directory>./</directory>
</testsuite>
</phpunit>
```

bootstrap.php

```
<?php

date_default_timezone_set("America/Mexico_City");
// Define root path of project
defined('BASE_PATH')
    || define('BASE_PATH', realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../'));

// Define path to application directory
defined('APPLICATION_PATH')
    || define('APPLICATION_PATH', realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../application'));

// Define application environment
defined('APPLICATION_ENV')
    || define('APPLICATION_ENV', (getenv('APPLICATION_ENV') ? getenv('APPLICATION_ENV') : 'development'));

// Ensure library/ is on include_path
set_include_path(implode(PATH_SEPARATOR, array(
    realpath(APPLICATION_PATH . '/../../../library'),
    get_include_path(),
)));

require_once '../library/Zend/Loader/Autoloader.php';
Zend_Loader_Autoloader::getInstance();
```

El framework Zend lo tengo en la carpeta library un nivel más arriba.

estoy usando `"zendframework/zend-test": "^3.3"`

de antemano gracias por la ayuda!